# Optimization Challenge- Merging arrays

Tags: javascript

I'd like to host a challenge,
I've made a JavaScript function that is very unoptimized and can be improved in a million ways,
Could you optimize it to the max?

```
function merge(array1, array2, array3, array4, array5){
  var result = [];
  var arrays = [array1, array2, array3, array4, array5];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    var array = arrays[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      var item = array[j];
      if (result.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        result.push(item);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

const x = ['hi','hello','hey']
const y = ['apple','banana','orange']
const z = ['hie','helloe','heye']
const w = ['applei','bananai','orangei']
const e = ['hio','helloo','heyo']

console.log(merge(x,y,z,w,e));
```

Good luck optimizing it as best as you can!

I'll give out a 2 hints:

1. Instead of multiple parameters, you could turn it into one parameter that supports infinite arrays,
2. Instead of using function(), there is an another way that uses less memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest parameter syntax can be used to allow passing in any number of arrays. Then, we can flatten the parameter to concatenate all the arrays together. Finally, creating a `Set` from it and converting back to an array with spread syntax removes duplicates.

```js
const merge = (...arrs) => [...new Set(arrs.flat())];

const x = ['hi','hello','hey']
const y = ['apple','banana','orange']
const z = ['hie','helloe','heye']
const w = ['applei','bananai','orangei']
const e = ['hio','helloo','heyo']

console.log(merge(x, y, z, w, e));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function merge(...arr) {
  const result = new Set();
  arr.forEach((item) => item.forEach((value) => result.add(value)));
  return Array.from(result);
}

const x = ['hi','hello','hey'];
const y = ['apple','banana','orange'];
const z = ['hie','helloe','heye'];
const w = ['applei','bananai','orangei'];
const e = ['hio','helloo','heyo'];
const mergedArr = merge(x, y, z, w, e);

console.log(mergedArr);
```

Comment: It is quite correct but turning it into a function makes it more optimized and can be used as many times as wanted.

Comment: @Plain_69 This is not correct as the code in the question also removes duplicates.